# How do I get Bokeh to update a plot displaying some measure vs epoch when using keras fit_generator?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, bokeh

I have seen it once before briefly in a presentation, someone was plotting:

- loss/validation_loss vs epoch
- accuracy/validation_accuracy vs epoch

The special thing was that this person was using a Bokeh plot that udpates itself after each epoch. How is such a feat accomplished?

Comment: can you include some examples or sample plotting data?

Comment: Let me try to find some examples. I will post back here.

Comment: See [Issue #1101: Bokeh Support for Keras ](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1101). I made a notebook [Live loss plots in Jupyter Notebook for Keras with matplotlib](https://gist.github.com/stared/dfb4dfaf6d9a8501cd1cc8b8cb806d2e), if it helps.

Comment: See this library: https://github.com/stared/livelossplot

Answer (score 2):

The example from Piotr Migdal using a callback actually looks pretty nice. You could re-run the plotter every epoch as I do for some small monitoring application at home integrating this into the callback function. I quickly extracted the relevant code assuming you have some data frame with you plotting data:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bplt

data = pd.read_csv(...)

bplt.output_file('myplots.html', title='Myplots')

p = bplt.figure(title='Keras Live Loss')
p.line(data['epoch'], data['loss'], line_color='blue', line_width=1)
p.line(data['epoch'], data['val_loss'], line_color='red', line_width=1, line_dash='dotted')

bplt.show(p)
```

Another thing you could try would be a steaming application which looks promising but I never tried it before to be honest. Maybe this helps:
https://www.continuum.io/content/painless-streaming-plots-bokeh

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bokeh's Jupyter integration to do this live in a notebook. I made a sample notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/31e11f36683deef6572d14a14c400f51), though just with dummy data.

To use this with Keras, I would use the `on_batch_end` or `on_epoch_end` callbacks to call the `update` function from the notebook.

Briefly, the relevant code is:

```
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import numpy as np
output_notebook()

p = figure()
r = p.line([], [], legend='loss')
show(p, notebook_handle=True)

def update(losses):
    x = np.arange(len(losses))
    r.data_source.data.update(x=x, y=losses)
    push_notebook()

# Train here, and periodically call `update(losses)`.
```

To this, you may wish to add

- Exit early from `update` if not much time has passed since the last call.
- Plot both training and validation loss.
- Smooth the data with e.g. `scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d` and plot the unsmoothed data with lower opacity.
- Subsample the data before passing it to `r.data_source.data.update`. In my experiments with loss histories of N=~200,000 points, I found that the time to call `update` grew to more than a second if I plotted the whole thing, but if I used `indices = np.floor(np.linspace(0, len(y)-1, 1000)).astype(int) if len(y) > 10000 else slice(0, None)` to generate a reduced index set, I could always keep the time to around 60 ms (including time for the smoothing, which didn't really scale strongly with N).
- Run this in a separate thread or process. I haven't done this yet, since, with my .06 s/call for update, I only add 6% to my training time if I consider running `update` once per batch but actually only run it once per second.

Of course, you could alternately use Tensorboard, but if you don't need all its other features, it's probably overkill compared to a simple few dozen lines for Bokeh and you need to start a separate process and think about log dirs and capture the right summaries and you just can't be bothered.